# How to clear a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I clear a one dimensional numpy array?

if it was a list, I would do this:

```
my_list = []
```

How to do this with numpy?

**edited:**

What I mean by clearing is to remove all element in the same array.
And for list I had to use `my_list.clear()`

Comment: That doesn't clear a python list at all. That assigns a *new empty list* to some variable. In any case, you can do the same thing for a numpy array, but you can't actually "clear" a numpy array because they cannot change size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a numpy array is created a certain memory is allocated based on its size. If you do not initialize it then it will contain garbage value. numpy array are of fixed size and its size has to given while creating it.

Example:

```
np.empty(10)
```

Creates a numpy array of size 10 which is not initlized.

So to clear it you have to understand with what want value you want to clear it with ? clear all the value to 0 or to some random values ? But you cannot set it to size 0.

Now lets say you want to clear all the value to 0 then you can do:

```
a = np.empty(10)
print (hex(id(a)))
# This is not actually clearing but creating 
# a new numpy array of zeros just like list l = []
a = np.zeros_like(a)
print (hex(id(a)))
# This sets all the value of numpy array to 0 using broadcasting
a[:] = 0
print (hex(id(a)))
```

List are variable length data structures. When you say `l = []` you are  not actually clearing a new list but creating a new empty list.

```
l = [1,2,3]
print (hex(id(l)))
l = []
print (hex(id(l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'clear'? The code

```
my_list = []
```

just overwrites whatever was stored as `my_list` previously, regardless whether it was a list, array or whatever. If that is what you wish to do, you use the exact same syntax if `my_list` was an array.

If by clear you mean delete all elements in the list, then use

```
my_list.clear()
```

which deletes all the elements in the list and keeps the `id`:

```
>>> a = [4]*2
>>> a
[4, 4]
>>> id(a)
140202631135872
>>> a.clear()
>>> a
[]
>>> id(a)
140202631135872
```

There exists no equivalent to this for numpy arrays, since it is not possible to change the number of elements in a numpy array.

If you wish to simply set all the values in the array to 0:

```
>>> arr = np.random.randn(3)
>>> arr
array([-1.11074625, -0.12784997, -0.53716969])
>>> id(arr)
140203438053536
>>> arr[:] = 0
>>> arr
array([0., 0., 0.])
>>> id(arr)
140203438053536
```